# Paypal - Failed to connect to host Input Server Uri = https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com/

Tags: paypal

I have tried many solutions, whichever one I went through I still get the same response message:

> "Failed to connect to host Input Server Uri = https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com/".

Card details are '4111111111111111'.

Answer (score 4):

Most probably the issue is related to TLS upgrade. Paypal updated its services to require TLS 1.2 for all HTTPS connections. check [here](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1914&viewlocale=en_US)

Use the below code  before the payment processing code in your application

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Also make sure your server is TLS 1.2 enabled.

Hopefully it will solve your issue.

Comment: Hi Fakir Mohan...  thanks for your reply... i have tried the solution provided by you but still facing the same issue... i.e "Failed to connect to host Input Server Uri "

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:
If you are using Jboss 5.1 use java version Java 1.7. (note: JBoss 5.1 don't support java 8).

after that add a VM argument to the JBoss VM arguments for TLS protocol Jboss handling. (eclipse JBoss Launch Configuration)

-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2

If you are using eclipse add the argument in the VM argument section.

Note: Also change the runtime environment of your JBoss runtime in Eclipse to avoid an Unsupported major.minor version xx runtime error.

Also set the Compiler Compliance Level of your Java compiler in Eclipse to appropriate version.

[image: VM Arguments]

Comment: Hi just recently we've made some solutions on this issue and we've found upgrading to Java 1.7 is the best option if you are using Jboss 5.1 then add this to the VM arguments in your start script -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Java.client ? If yes what's the version of Java . Pilot payflow pro now supports only tls1.2 only

Answer (score 0):

The Test card details have changed so that might be why you are getting the error while using the card "4111111111111111" so try using any card number from this link to see if that fixes your issue:

http://www.getcreditcardnumbers.com/

Comment: thanks for your reply.... I tried with 3-4 different card number but still getting the very same error.

Comment: this is the what i am getting when i have checked with fiddler         -                         HTTPS handshake to pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com (for #212) failed. System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. < The message received was unexpected or badly formatted

Win32 (SChannel) Native Error Code: 0x80090326